# Does HP webOS have a WYSWYG GUI design tool?

Tags: webos, mojo, enyo

I hope to migrate one of my apps to HP webOS.  Does webOS have WYSIWYG GUI tool that integrates with Mojo or Enyo, or do have to use a HTML/CSS/JavaScript editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a WYSIWYG editor for Mojo apps called Ares.  You can check it out at: https://ares.palm.com/Ares/login.html

You'll need to set up a developer account first.  It has been reported that Ares will be updated to support Enyo.  When working with Enyo apps (or Mojo apps for that matter) you can use pretty much any environment/IDE that you prefer.

Comment: Check out the roadmap for webOS.  Ares 2 is scheduled for April.  Here's a link:  http://www.webosroundup.com/2012/01/webos-open-source-plan-announced-and-enyo-open-sourced/

Comment: Ares 2.0 and Enyo 2.1 in April, thats awesome news. I think HP going Open Source was the best thing they could do for this system. If only hardware could be created.

Answer (score 0):

The other two pretty decent options are Eclipse and JetBrains WebStorm. Both have fairly decent Mojo plugins, though I have been unimpressed by their Enyo offerings to date.